# Need to create sample dataset

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create sample data set with three variables using their allowed minimum and maximum values.

I tried `random()` and from `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator` `import make_blobs`

I need to create N samples for 3 variables using their allowed minimum and maximum values:

```
Input : 
Samples = 10

A_min = 10  
A_max = 100

B_min = 1  
B_max = 3

C_min = 2  
C_max = 10
```

Expected Output : Random, unique, uniform distributed data set, something like below

#### Expected output:

```
     A  B   C  
    10  1   2
    10  3   4
    20  1   10
    20  3   6
    50  1   8
    50  2   10
    70  1   2
    70  2   6
   100  1   8
   100  3   10
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment. Stack Overflow will not help you cheat. Share what you have tried and where you failed specifically. We'll be glad to point you in the right direction but we will not write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using random.choice function you can do it like

```py
from random import choice

a_range = range(10,101)
b_range = range(2,4)
c_range = range(2,11)

data = [[choice(a_range), choice(b_range), choice(c_range)] for _ in range(10)]
print(data)
```

Comment: just replace the 1st line with ```a_range = range(10,101, 10)``` it will give range with interval of 10